# How to convert the font objects in a PDF to CFF

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, file-conversion

PDFs which use CFF fonts instead of Type 1 fonts are much smaller. Running a PDF through a ghostscript conversion will indeed produce a PDF with Type1C (CFF) fonts. But this also "re-renders" the PDF, getting rid of certain factors such as the print/screen distinction (if used). It there any way to convert a PDF with Type 1 fonts to a PDF which is otherwise identical, but which uses Type1C fonts instead, i.e., just converting the font objects?

Comment: Are you open to a paid/commercial solution? Or are you only for FOSS?

Comment: I'm a FOSS guy.

Comment: Did you ever find a FOSS solution then? If so, you should post here as an answer, so it can help others.

Comment: I wrote something of my own, but it only partially worked. So no.

Comment: Since apparently there are no FOSS solutions to your question, perhaps you should revisit the original issue. "are much smaller" why is having smaller PDF files important for you?